# iOS: CSS3 animation breaks scrolling on div

Tags: ios, css, scroll, transform, scale

I'm developing a web-app, based on the Dribbble API. In this app I have a div which shows all comments with a max-height of 200px, so if there's more than 200px worth on comments, the div gets scrollable. So far so good, works as intended on iOS. 
However, when I add a Scale transfrm to this div (to mimic iOS's folder opening animation), scrolling the div breaks entirely. You can see the live version here: http://maxsteenbergen.com/longshot/
Is this fixable by setting a a new style using jQ's webkitAnimationEnd or is this without solution?

EDIT: In the meantime I found that using two fingers to scroll the div works but obviously, this is not how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that scrolling DIV's don't work on older versions of iOS - it might be worth having a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement native iOS UI and achieve much better UI feedback. especially on scroll view. To obtain data from Dribbble API you may use 3rd-party Dribbble iOS SDK: https://github.com/agilie/dribbble-ios-sdk